# Immersion from sphere to $ \Bbb{R}^{n +1}$.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, jacobian, submanifold

Let $S^n=\{(x_1,\dots,x_{n+1})∈ \Bbb{R}^{n+1}\mid x_1^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2=1\}$.
There is natural inclusion from $S^n$ to $ \Bbb{R}^{n +1}$.

I want to prove this natural inclusion is **immersion**.
I want to prove this by **calculating rank of Jacobi matrix**.
But I'm having trouble because I cannot figure out **what the Jacobi matrix is**.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your definition gives a property of an $n$-tuple but the property mentions an extra coordinate. Usually n-sphere is defined as the points in R^(n+1) satisfying the equation you mention.

Comment: Remember the standard projection charts on $S^n$, or also the stereographic projection charts. Take the inverse of those charts and compose with the inclusion map then you'll have a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and you can compute the Jacobian in those coordinates explicitly. The rank of the Jacobian doesn't depend on coordinates and hence you'll have your immersion.

Comment: That's a lot of contexts missing. Do you know how $\mathbb S^n$ is a smooth manifold? What is the charts? Do you know is the definition of the "Jacobi matrix"?

Answer (score 1):

Fix one of the $2(n+1)$ charts of one of the most natural atlants of $S^n$:

$$\phi_i^+\colon U_i^+:=\{x_i>0\} \to B(0,1)\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n} \text{ by sending } (x_1,\dots, x_{n+1})\mapsto (x_1,\dots \hat{x_i} \dots, x_{n+1})$$

The inverse map sends
$$(t_1,\dots ,t_n)\mapsto (t_1,\dots, \sqrt{1-(t_1^2+\dots t_n^2)}, \dots , t_n)$$

Now that you fixed the atlant, then the inclusion function $i\colon S^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ will be locally with respect to the charts $\phi_i^+$

$i\circ (\phi_i^+)^{-1}\colon B(0,1)\to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by sending

$$(t_1,\dots ,t_n)\mapsto (t_1,\dots, \sqrt{1-(t_1^2+\dots t_n^2)}, \dots , t_n)$$

The Jacobian of the function is

$$J=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & \dots &  0\\
0 & 1 & \dots  \\
\dots  & \dots  \\
\frac{-2t_1}{\sqrt{1-(t_1^2+\dots t_n^2)}} & \dots & \dots 
\frac{-2t_n}{\sqrt{1-(t_1^2+\dots t_n^2)}}\\
\dots & \dots \\
0& 0 \dots  &1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Of course $rk(J)=n$, that shows the differential is injective for any point $U_i^+$ of the chart. You can prove this for each of the $2(n+1)$ charts that cover $S^n$. Hence $i$ is an immersion.